# How to set specific values to arrays in a loop? - C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I'm in a beginner programming course and our assignment is make a program of a game that starts with 10 people. You start with the first person and count people till 3, then drop that person. You keep doing this until there is only one person left.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n[10] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, i = 0;
    int * ptrN = &n[i];

    for( i = 0; n[i]; n[i+3]){

        if (n[i+3] = 1){ 
            *ptrN = 0; 
        }
        else if (n[i] = 0)
            continue;
        else
            printf("Wrong");
    }
    printf("The value of n0 %d\tn1 %d\tn2 %d\tn3 %d\tn4 %d\tn5 %d\tn6 %d\tn7 %d\tn8 %d\tn9 %d", n[0], n[1], n[2], n[3], n[4], n[5], n[6], n[7], n[8], n[9]);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm far off from my answer right now but I'm already encountering problems. When I run the above code, it will only change the value of n[0] and then will exit program. Would appreciate any guidance. Thank you

Comment: Oh, and I was trying to set the values of n[] to 0 once that person is dropped. How can I set an exit to my loop once there is only 1 "1" left?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: `ptrN` always points to the first element of the array. Updating `i` doesn't update `ptrN` automatically.

Comment: you need to use `==` to compare, `=` is for assigning.

Comment: Perhaps it would be better if you described what the program ought to do in English first.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala The program is supposed to do what I put above the code.

Comment: @Barmar -- So if I understand correctly; in my first if statement, the program is counting to n[2] and recognizing its value is 1, but because ptrN only can point to n[0], it will set that value to 0 instead of n[2]? Would I have to make a pointer for each array element?

Comment: Why do you think you need a pointer at all? Just write `n[i] = 0;`

Comment: Another problem: your `for` loop never increments `i`. What do you expect `n[i+3]` in the third part of the loop header to do?

Comment: @Barmar To be honest, I'm not sure why I would need a pointer, but we've just learned about them so I was taking a guess that it would be needed here too. And I was expecting n[i+3] to add 3 to each i, but looking back at the code, I think I should just have it as i+3.

Comment: It should be `i = i + 3` or `i += 3`.

Comment: But I suspect that's not what you're really supposed to do. You're supposed to count 3 entries that have `1` in them, and skip over the 0's. If you just increment `i` by 3, you'll keep processing the same entries, even though you already dropped them.

Comment: @Barmar Yeah you're right.. I've no clue how to skip over the 0's though. Would I need to make a new loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments:

1. Use `==` to compare, `=` is for assignment.
2. You don't need to use a pointer. You can use `n[i]`
3. You need to increment `i`.
4. You need to skip over the `0`'s.

As you mentioned, you also need to stop when there is only one `1` left.

There are more than one way to solve that but you could do it by having a counter for how many `1`'s there are and have a `while`-loop that ends when the counter is down to `1`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int n[10] = {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}, count = 10;

    /* `i` needs to start at -1 so that we start counting:
     *     "0, 1, 2. n[2] is out!"
     *  instead of counting:
     *     "1, 2, 3. n[3] is out!"
     */
    int i = -1;

    while (count > 1) {

        /* We need to count three of those persons that are not out.
         * That means we have to search for the next person that is not
         * out (by skipping over `0`) and repeat that three times.
         *
         * If we just increase `i` by 3 ( `(i + 3) % 10` ) then we are
         * not checking how many of those persons between `n[i]` and
         * `n[(i + 3) % 10]` needed to be skipped over.
         *
         * So repeat three times:
         */
        for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {

            /* This will search for the next person that is not out by 
             * increasing `i` by one until `n[i]` is not `0`:
             */
            do {
                i = (i + 1) % 10;
            } while (n[i] == 0); // Check next person if this one is out.

        } // I forgot to close this bracket in my first version of the answer

        n[i] = 0;
        count--;
    }

    printf("The value of n0 %d\tn1 %d\tn2 %d\tn3 %d\tn4 %d\tn5 %d\tn6 %d\tn7 %d\tn8 %d\tn9 %d", n[0], n[1], n[2], n[3], n[4], n[5], n[6], n[7], n[8], n[9]);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Can you explain the for loop though?. Im confused on where the j comes in. I believe the first person who would be out would be n[2] right? And for your i value, would it not need to be i = (i + 3) % 10;? Sorry for all the questions. Im a pretty big newbie D:

Comment: I will add more comments to better explain my code.